# ICA on RGB channels in python

Tags: python, signal-processing

I have processed a fingertip video, split it into r, g and b channels. Filtered each channel using butter worth band pass filter. Now I want to do ICA on them to remove the noise. I don't understand how to construct the matrix for the ICA.
Do I have to do ICA separately on each channel, or should it be done combined on all channels?

This is the image of r,g,b after processing respectively, all with respect to time in x axis.

#### Red channel:

[image]

#### Green channel

[image]

#### Blue channel:

[image]

It is based on [this paper](http://www.ep.liu.se/ecp/129/002/ecp16129002.pdf)

Comment: Can you share your data?

Comment: @NoamPeled Link to video of fingertip: https://drive.google.com/open?id=133VvxeleSwCEBwr5CokC3Ie7nuslR4pd Link to code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1FpKFPF3EHjeez6eGYZBNiBNoZLGYcDOs

Answer (score 0):

This is a hip shot from my part.
As I remember from uni you can make one large array of every row of pixels, per image. I think the important part is that you are consistent (i.e. you can use columns instead of rows). By consistent I mean that when you reconstruct the image afterwards, splice the array the same way you constructed it.

I think that they do the FFT, PCA and ICA on each color separately. But I can't see them explicitly stating it. I think so because I don't see the point in filtering and normalizing the colors separately and then combine them before the ICA, FFT n' PCA.